How to interface with a UNIX port?
I have encountered this same question in numerous forms over the past year, and have not been able to find the solution I am after. As the question has yet again reared its head, I am asking here with renewed vigor that what I am after is indeed possible.
In summary - how does one practically interface with a UNIX port ?
To illustrate the answer I am looking for, I will describe my thought framework:
Historically, if I am writing software in some language, I may occassionaly need to interface with another language, or store some variable on my system for later use, once the programme terminates.
I have found a convenient way of achieving this to write to a file. I find this straightforward in all languages I work with - whether using fprintf in C or the append character >> in bash. It also has many other bonuses - such as being editable via a CLI directly, following UNIX permission settings for regular files, etc, etc.
When communicating over a network, there must be a stream of some sort accepting input and returning output. My question is - how do I interface with this stream via a file or files ?
I have limited experience with UNIX sockets, which have presence as system files. I have limited experience using hardware serial ports on my PC - these write their output to a system file.
So - how do I practically read and write from a port on my system ? For example, practically, how would I achieve this in bash or C ?
OS Specs:
I am using Linux.

Are you on Linux? You first have to create the socket, but after that you can write to it just like a normal file. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336876/simple-shell-script-to-send-socket-message

If you're looking for a (special) file in the filesystem that would let you access a network stream — sometime like /net/com/google/tcp/80 — I don't believe there is one.  If you're looking for a shell command that lets you easily access network streams, that's netcat or nc.  And if you want to open a networking stream from within a C program, you need to call socket and then either connect or bind and accept.

You MAY just want to use scp or ssh if you're using a shell. Consider also using ssh with a coprocess.

bash lets you redirect I/o to a socket using psuedo files like /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT - see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html for details.

In C you use the sockets API. Get the book "Unix Network Programming" for a full understanding.

ksh93(+) supports addressing like /net/com/google/tcp/80 (or similar). It may only be later versions. So when you say Unix (vs Linux), you'll have to do further research about when that feature was added, what version does your Unix have, etc. Good luck.

yet another option to consider: socat; you can pass data directly via ports, you can interact with files via ports ... there are a lot of ways to use socat to pass data between processes on different hosts

Do you have to do it from bash? I find dealing with sockets easier from i.e. Perl or Ruby, but probably any programming language you are familiar with can do it.

Networking can either be extremely excruciating or very simple but you do have some pretty cool ways to do it in either Bash or C.
Bash:
I wont usually use bash for networking but I have played with Netcat which is a pretty simple tool to read and write data across your networks.
if you aren't a fan of that, all i could recommend is scp
C:
As someone else has already mentioned, the sockets API would likely be best so here's a basic example of using it, also you can refer to the documentation here.
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in a = {.sin_family = AF_INET, .sin_port = 0x901F};
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&a, sizeof(a));
    listen(s, 1);
    for(;;) {
        int c = accept(s, 0, 0);
        send(c, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nHello!", 19, 0);
        close(c);
    }
}

This is a very minimalist web server that holds a string on a local port, just use
curl http://localhost:8080

to take a look into the port.
Hope I helped, have a good day!
-Andrew

In How to Answer, note the section Answer Well-Asked Questions, and the bullet points therein regarding questions that "...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem", or those that "...require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions".

I'd argue that this falls into both categories -- generally, we'd want "how do I do X in bash?" and "how do I do X in C?" to be two completely separate questions; and there are whole books written about the socket API, so any question so broad as to ask how to use the whole thing (as opposed to describing a narrow, specific problem encountered during its use) clearly can't be answered in full in the scope of a Stack Overflow question.
